# Python. Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 35

Tags: python-2.7

In this exercise, and i've checked the other threads, regarding this, i don't get the problem. The gold_room function doesn't come into play. When i taunt the bear twice, i'm dead.(so is assume, the loop works)
While the loop checks if bear_moved is true AND i typed door, it doesn't start gold_room()
(and there's no error message from python to help me on the way, so i'm stumped at this one)

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full with gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input('>')
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead ("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!!")


def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here"
    print "The bear has a bunch of money"
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door"
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True: 
        next = raw_input('>')

        if next == 'take money':
            dead("The bear looks at you, then pimpslaps your face off.")
        elif next == 'taunt bear' and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == 'taunt bear' and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your crotch off.")
        elif next == 'door ' and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."

def cthulu_room():
    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input('>')

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead ("Well, that was tasty...")
    else:
        cthulu_room()

def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!!"
    exit (0)


def start():
    print "You are  in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Wich one do you take?"

    next = raw_input(">")


    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around  the room until you starve.")


start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elif next == 'door ' and bear_moved:
```

should be

```
elif next == 'door' and bear_moved:
```

Comment: Giant *face palm*. Missed that one completely. I feel so stupid right now.. Thanks for pointing this out. Next time, i'll scan my code more and better, before asking questions.